# Android : How to check whether user is logged in or not in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying Facebook integration in android and mainly I am facing 3 problems.

1) When user click on **Login with Facebook** button and if user is not logged in, then it is opening Facebook app which I have installed from play store instead of popup.

2) I want to check weather user is logged in or not if yes, then app just ask for the permission that **Test App will access ....** and if I press **Ok** it should move to next screen I mean it should not ask for user credential that is Email or facebbok ID and password.

3) Logout functionality.

So basically I got code from this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) but it uses **Shared Preference** to store user data, so basically if I logged out from my facebook app, it will not ask for login again, so my question is how to remove this shared preference and instead of shared preference what should I use.

And last thing is I have implemented logout functionality but it is not working properly I don't know why.

Below is my full code.

```
public class FacebookLogin extends Activity {

    Button facebookLogin;
    Button facebookLogout;

    private static String APP_ID = "myapp-key";

    private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    String access_token;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.facebbok_login);

        facebookLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebookLogin);
        facebookLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebooklogout);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

        facebookLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
                loginToFacebook();
            }
        });

        facebookLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
                logoutFromFacebook();
            }
        });
    }

    public void loginToFacebook() {

        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(FacebookLogin.this, ShowVideo.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
            Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this,
                    new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();

                            Intent mIntent = new Intent(FacebookLogin.this,
                                    ShowVideo.class);
                            startActivity(mIntent);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void logoutFromFacebook() {
        Log.d("Image Button", "Inside logout");

        mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
                if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent mIntent = new Intent(FacebookLogin.this,
                                    SplashScreen.class);
                            startActivity(mIntent);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using the OLD facebook api, it isn't a good practice. I really advice you to go for facebook sdk 3.6. most of the methods are deprecated. [follow this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) it is self explained. there is a class called UiLifeCylceHelper which will solve your first 2 problems easily. good luck

Comment: @Coderji, Ok, i have used faebook sdk 3.6, now can you tell me how can i implement my loginToFacebook() function.

Answer (score -2):

When a user is logged in, you can know that by using AccessToken or Profile. There is no need of sharedpreferences. The facebook SDK takes care of that. You can see if a person is already logged in by checking AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() and Profile.getCurrentProfile().

Use [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) as reference.